# Pie Chart - How to show gender percentage based on Sql Count statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I`m trying to show gender percentage into a pie chart using count statement and placing it in dataset. I`ve retrived the data but i have no idea on how to bind it in XY because all the data is in a single dataTable variable.

So my flow for the program,

1. user choose table name from drop down list
2. user generate report
3. ddl for x and y is filled with column shown in the report above
4. user choose the x and y value which has the column name from the ddl

For the database, it only have id, name and gender.

If it is just reading the value from DB, then i have managed to do it using dataView(), but for this i really dont know how to do it.

p/s. new in C# and asp.net. Appreciate all the help and TQVM in advanced.

1st part code - taking user drop down list and creating the dataset

```
public void testGraph()
    {
        string ddlX = ddlTestGraphX.SelectedValue;
        string ddlY = ddlTestGraphY.SelectedValue;
        CodeDB db = new CodeDB();
        db.Open();

        //SET UP THE DATA TO PLOT
        string userInput = DDLTableName.SelectedValue;
        if (userInput == "tblparticipant")
        {
            DataSet dsX = db.getDataSet2(ddlX, userInput);
            DataTable dataX = dsX.Tables[0];
            DataSet dsY = db.getDataSetCount(ddlY, userInput);
            DataTable dataY = dsY.Tables[0];

            string trimmedUserInput = userInput.Remove(0, 3);
            try
            {
                if (rbPieChart.Checked == true)
                {
                    pieChart(trimmedUserInput, dataX, dataY);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Visible = true;
                lblError.Text = "Check Your drop down list";
            }
        }
}
```

2nd part code - displaying the pie chart

```
public void pieChart(string recTrimmedUserInput, DataTable recDataX, DataTable recDataY)
    {
        //BIND THE DATA TO THE CHART
        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
        Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add("CHART " + recTrimmedUserInput.ToUpper());
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(recDataX.AsDataView(), recDataY.AsDataView());

        //SET THE CHART TYPE TO BE PIE
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
        //Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P2}";
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
        Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "-90";

        //SET THE COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART TO BE A PRESET OF NONE 
        //DEFINE OUR OWN COLOR PALETTE FOR THE CHART 
        Chart1.Palette = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.None;
        //Chart1.PaletteCustomColors = new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Red };

        //Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#VALX , #VALY";
        Chart1.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P2}";

        //SET THE IMAGE OUTPUT TYPE TO BE JPEG
        Chart1.ImageType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageType.Jpeg;

        //ADD A PLACE HOLDER CHART AREA TO THE CHART
        //SET THE CHART AREA TO BE 3D
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
        Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

        //ADD A PLACE HOLDER LEGEND TO THE CHART
        //DISABLE THE LEGEND
        Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
        Chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#VALX";
        Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
    }
```

3rd part code - getting dataset

```
public DataSet getDataSetCount(string receivedDDL, string receivedUserInput)
    {
        string query = "Select " + receivedDDL +", count(id) as count From "+ receivedUserInput+" Group by "+ receivedDDL;
        if (con.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Table");

            ad.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any chart?

Comment: @HansKesting thats the thing. It doesnt shows anything. Lol.. if i change the parameter when i bindXY, to both recDataY.AsDataView(), recDataY.AsDataView(), then in the legend it shows male and female. However, the chart still doesnt show anything. When i debug it, it has retrieved the data in the form of itemArray, female = 2, male = 3

Comment: when i debug it, in dataTable dataY it contains 2 rows, and each rows contains 2 item array. row[0] = itemArray[0] = female and itemArray[1] = 2 and row[1] = itemArray[0] = male and itemArray[1] = 3.